# How to transform an Apple Mac Mini intro a reliable Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ssd, mac-mini, unix, efi

This question is about what steps are needed for transforming an Apple Mac Mini into an Ubuntu server.

Here are some areas:

- installing Ubuntu and making it to be bootable from EFI by default
- enabing CPU and fan control (by default it does not work)
- be sure that it will power on after power failure
- SSD configuring (assuming that the primary disk is a SSD and that you may have a HD as the second disk, nobody needs the DVD drive).

Answer (score 6):

First [install `rEFInd`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), and boot Ubuntu installer after.

Enable "Boot after power failure" by adding next line to /etc/rc.local:

```
 setpci -s 0:1f.0 0xa4.b=0
 setpci -s 00:03.0 0x7b.b=0x19
```

Install mac fan control:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mactel-support/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y macfanctld applesmc-dkms
```

For SSD tunning (you have to adapt to your config) here is my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
UUID=<...> /        ext4   noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=<...> /boot    vfat   defaults,noatime,discard    0   1
```

What is important to remember here:

- `/boot` is the `rEFInd` partition, as you can keep all in the same place.
- I added noatime,nodiratime to the / partition as this will lower the tear-down of the SSD.

Do noy add `discard` or `ext4discard` to the list of options because [instant TRIM will slow down your SSD](https://patrick-nagel.net/blog/archives/337) too much.

The optimal solution is to run [TRIM in a daily crob job](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/enable-trim-on-ssd-solid-state-drives.html), by running something like:

```
 fstrim -v /
```

Other resources:

- http://www.frozenindustries.com/2012/11/04/ubuntu-12-04-lts-on-an-apple-mac-mini-late-2012/

Comment: Thank you for creating this answer. My question is whether or not things have changed for the current generation. I'm planning on installing Ubuntu onto a PCIe 256 gig SSD on my brand new mac mini.

I specifically do not understand what:

`setpci -s 0:1f.0 0xa4.b=0`

Does. Also, are the backticks included? Normally backticks are used to quote code, but it seems you double backticked this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only issue would be the ability to power itself on after a power failure, this is what this line is supposed to enable. It depends on the chipset so you may need a different one. No back ticks needed.